# Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int \frac{x^2}{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int \frac{x^2}{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx$

What I try : Using Substution, $\displaystyle x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ and $\displaystyle dx =\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt$ also using $\displaystyle x^4-1=\frac{2(1+6t^2+t^4}{(1+t)^4}dt$

And $\displaystyle dx=(4t+4t^3)$

So $\displaystyle I =\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(1-t)^2}{(1+6t^2+t^4)\sqrt{t+t^3}}dt$

Now I did not understand How I solve it after that step.

Please have a look On that , Thanks

Comment: This [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bx%5E2%2F%28%28x%5E4+-+1%29+Sqrt%5Bx%5E4+%2B+1%5D%29%2C+x%5D) does not have *analytical* solution.

Comment: With Mathematica: $$\int \frac{x^2}{\left(x^4-1\right) \sqrt{x^4+1}} \, dx=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}
   x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{2}}+C$$

Comment: I suspect a very specific hard-to-guess trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It's strange. I have also Mathematica and it does not give your result (but gives the same formula given by Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: @NN2 .I use version  **13.3.0** and **14.0.0**  of Mathematica, give the same answers.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Mine is of version 12.0.0. Perhaps I need to upgrade it to a later version then.